# Rainbow CSV fails to determine the separator automatically: property not allowed

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code, separator

I had a problem of Rainbow CSV failing to determine the true separator in a file (pipe) and setting it to a wrong one (comma).

From [Rainbow CSV](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv) I learned that to make it determine a separator automatically for every file, I need to enable fixed sticky header line in VSC (done) and limit the settings to csv files only by typing

```
    "[csv][dynamic csv][tsv][csv (pipe)]": {
    "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true
},
```

in JSON config (done). However, the error I get is "Property [csv][dynamic csv][tsv][csv (pipe)] is not allowed." There is not much information on the Internet on how to allow this property.

Then to explicitly set a pipe separator for all csv files, I need to type this:

```
"files.associations": {
"*.dat": "csv (pipe)",
"*.csv": "csv (pipe)"
},
```

Again, "Property files.associations is not allowed."

No idea what to do here. Ready to provide additional details as setting the separator manually every time I open the file is nauseating.

---

VSCode:

```
Version: 1.79.2
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:59:55.818Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.19.0-43-generic
```

Rainbow CSV:

```
Name: Rainbow CSV
Id: mechatroner.rainbow-csv
Description: Highlight CSV and TSV files, Run SQL-like queries
Version: 3.7.0
Publisher: mechatroner
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv
```